# Convert the borders of a partially transparent PNG to an outline vector in SVG

Tags: svg, png

I'm seeking for a tool that can convert a PNG image like this:

[image]

To an SVG border outline like this:

[SVG Image](https://github.com/YuichiSemura/towerofyours/raw/master/kirinuki/jk1.svg)

I'm not sure whether the creator of this image traced the outline by hand. He used GIMP to create the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I already found out by [this](https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/04/26/how-to-create-svg-paths-easily-using-the-gimp/) article. It uses GIMP.

> Open the image you want to edit and use the select tools to remove
>   parts of the image until you get the shape that you want to produce
>   with your SVG path:
>
> Next use the magic wand to select all the areas that you just cut out.
>
> Now go to the Invert item from the Select menu.
>
> This will make the selection tool take the shape of the painted area,
>   as opposed to the transparent area. Now choose To Path from the Select
>   menu.
>
> In the Paths window, you will see a path has been created (it should
>   be called Selection. Right click on the path and choose Export Path
>
> Save the path on the filesystem.

Comment: Yeah that would work.  Remember to accept your own answer as the best answer, since you solved it.

Comment: I will, but I have to wait another 24 hours till I can.